# Error in configuring elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration

I'm configuring three node elasticsearch cluster. I'm getting following error while try to start first node using following

startup command

```
[cloud_user@mishai3c elasticsearch-6.2.4]$ ./bin/elasticsearch -d -p pid
```

error message

```
[2019-11-11T04:50:39,634][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [master] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2019-11-11T04:50:39,636][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [master] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max number of threads [3581] for user [cloud_user] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2019-11-11T04:50:39,666][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [master] stopping ...
```

I have tried to set up ulimit in /etc/security/limits.conf file by adding following line

```
@cloud_user      hard    nproc           4096
```

It's highly appriciate if anyone can help

Comment: Can you show ur elasticsearch.yml ??

Comment: Thanks for response. It my mistake so I'm going to change the question and post the answer also again thanks for response

Answer (score 1):

After changing limit.conf file,I have checked max thread limit by running ulimit -u command in terminal it still show previous value then 
Then I logout and log into server and run ulimit -u command then it show 4096.

Then I tried to start elasticsearch it works